# Show that the *gamma* function is holomorphic in $\{Re(z)>0\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Show that the *gamma* function
>
> $$\Gamma(z)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{z-1}dt$$
>
> Is holomorphic in $\{Re(z)>0\}$.

Ok, so I was told to try to solve this excercise by defining a sequence of functions

$$f_n=\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{n}e^{-t}t^{z-1}dt$$

And try to bound the $n$th term by a converging integral (I guess) in any compact subset $K \subset \{Re(z)>0\}$. However, Im not sure what is that I have to bound, and how. Any hints?

Comment: first you want to show that for any $z$ in the open right half-plane the sequence $f_n(z)$ converges. then, to establish that this limit function is in fact a holomorphic function of $z$ you require that the convergence is uniform when $z$ is restricted to a compact subset of the right half-plane. technically this requires setting useful bounds for the nasty bits of the integral

Comment: Yes I know! thats what I said precisely I don't know what is the nasty bit I should bound!

Comment: a useful fact is that $|t^{z-1}|=t^{\mathfrak{Re}(z)-1}$

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using Morera's Theorem instead, which states that a continuous function $f$ is holomorphic in an open region $\Omega$ if the integral of $f$ over every triangle $\Delta$ is $0$ whenever the triangle and its interior is contained in $\Omega$.

The integral function you have for $\Gamma(z)$ is continuous by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. You can use Fubini's theorem to interchange orders of integration in order to prove that
$$
          \oint_{\Delta} \Gamma(z)dz = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}\left(\oint_{\Delta}e^{(-1+z)\ln t}dz\right)dt = 0.
$$

Comment: Could you explain we can use Fubini's theorem? Do we know that the function is absolutely Lebesgue integrable?