# $z\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-zx^2/2}dx$ is analytic in $\{z\in \mathbb{C}, \Re z>0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, analytic-functions

I am looking at the proof of the Fourier transform of a Gaussian, that is, for $z\in \mathbb C$ with $\Re z>0$, we have $\mathcal{F}(e^{-\frac{z|x|^2}{2}})(p)=\frac{1}{z^{d/2}}e^{-\frac{|p|^2}{2z}},$ where we interpret $z^{d/2}$ as $(\sqrt{z})^d$, and the branch cut of the square root is chosen along the negative real axis.

The proof is completed by showing that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-zx^2/2}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt z}$.

This is true for $z>0$ by applying the change of variables $y=\sqrt{z}x$.

For general $z\in \mathbb C$ it says this follows by analytic continuation.

To apply analytic continuation I need to know that the function
$$z\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-zx^2/2}dx$$ is analytic in $\{z\in \mathbb{C}, \Re z>0\}$.

How can I show this? One method I thought of is Morera's theorem, but I don't know how to guarantee that Fubini's theorem apply here to exchange the integrals. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: $\text{Re}(z)>0$ so the integral is exponentially decaying. This is more than enough to apply Fubini for Morera. You can also apply the holomorphic version of differentiation under the integral. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4120068/568204) for more details. There I give the application to the Gamma function, but the first part is still relevant here.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for a great theorem. Could you be more explicit about why the Fubini works because the integral is exponentially decaying? I don't know how to show that the double integral will be finite.

Comment: Look at the theorem I quoted. Surely you can try to come up with a dominating function $g_a$ which works? In fact making a change of variables, you’ll see that the Gaussian integral is **extremely** closely related to the Gamma function (you don’t need to change variables… I’m just pointing out these two are very closely related). So 95% of what I wrote there (and the types of estimates and dominating functions I’m coming up with there) will work here as well. So I strongly suggest reading the details there more closely.

Comment: @peek-a-boo So I think for any closed curve $\gamma$, we can take $a=\min |z|$ in $\gamma$ and uniformly bound $e^{-zx^2/2}$ by $e^{-ax^2/2}$, which will be integrable in $\mathbb R$ and then is just a constant so integrable over $\gamma$ as well, which will bound the original function over the double integral. Is this correct?

Comment: yup that’s it..